# Can you have multiple valid SSL certificates in the same store at the same time?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Is it possible to have 2 valid certs for the same site in the same store? ie cert1 valid from 2011 to 2013 and cert2 valid from 2012 to 2015

Comment: Generally, you can, but which language/plaform are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, but that doesn't mean that the system you're doing it for can use them. Tomcat for example uses a fixed alias name.

Comment: i specify find by thumbprint in my solution, i just need to know if i can have 2 certs for the same site coexisting in the store - so i can install the new one in advance, and change the thumbprint value at any point to the new one with minimal downtime